# Opencv: rbg->hsv->rgb is lossless?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, rgb, hsv

Here is some test of converting rgb->hsv->rgb:

```
def rgb2hsv_opencv(img_rgb):
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    return img_hsv

def hsv2rgb_opencv(img_hsv):
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
    return img_rgb

img_bgr = cv2.imread('00000.png')

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img_hsv = rgb2hsv_opencv(img_rgb)

img_rgb2 = hsv2rgb_opencv(img_hsv)

cv2.imwrite('debug_1.png', img_rgb)
cv2.imwrite('debug_2.png', img_rgb2)

print('diff:', np.max(np.fabs(img_rgb - img_rgb2)))
```

Images look the same but for some reason `diff` is not zero, is it expected?

Comment: These operations use floating point numbers that are rounded to integers. The rounding can result in small changes in value.

Comment: For my image max abs diff was 255, but images look the same visually.

Answer (score 2):

Actually [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) have some note on this topic:

> If you use cvtColor with 8-bit images, the conversion will have some
> information lost. For many applications, this will not be noticeable
> but it is recommended to use 32-bit images in applications that need
> the full range of colors or that convert an image before an operation
> and then convert back.

So adding `img_rgb = img_rgb.astype(np.float32)` before using non-linear conversions helps, it reduced max abs diff to `diff: 0.00011444092`
and adding `img_rgb = img_rgb / 255.0` helps even more, it reduced max abs diff to `diff: 4.172325e-07`

Comment: If your image is 8-bit, the hue maps to a range 0..179 rather than 0..359. That is in order to stay below 255. So the Hues only have a granularity of 2 degrees of Hue which will catch you out when you convert back to RGB. If your image is float, the Hues map to a range 0..359.9999.

Answer (score 1):

> For HSV, hue range is [0,179], saturation range is [0,255], and value range is [0,255]. Different software use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges. [[source]](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)

So if you convert RGB (256^3) to HSV(180x256x256) and backward, you cannot get the same color resolution, from simple reason that you had a half of color resolution that before conversion to HSV.

Comment: Note: CV permit also 32Floats (so ranges are less important), and OP could use `cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL` and `cv.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL` to get better values.

Comment: You mean loss of information is happens on HSV to RGB conversion?

Comment: Looks like with `FULL` the range is 256, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8c0b0714e76efef4a8ca2a7c410c60e55c5e9829/modules/imgproc/src/color_hsv.dispatch.cpp#L264 `int hrange = _src.depth() == CV_32F ? 360 : (!full ? 180 : 256);`